# There are no files in the solution explorer when writing the driver

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio

I tried writing a driver on Windows. I used this [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows-hardware/drivers/gettingstarted/writing-a-very-small-kmdf--driver). But I got the problem:

```
In the Solution Explorer window, right-click KmdfHelloWorld and choose Add > New Item.
In the Add New Item dialog box, select C++ File. For Name, enter "Driver.c".
```

In the Solution Explorer window, there are no files other than Package Manifest

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: `KmdfHelloWorld` is not a file, it's the name of the project.

Comment: In the solution explorer no any C ++ file

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is because you don't create a visual c++ project,

Be sure that you have selected the right option in Step 2 of the guide:
Templates > **Visual C++** > Windows Driver > KMDF.

[image]

Comment: @MadokaMagica if you have done so, this is a very weird issue, maybe you could try to reinstall your visual studio environment, be sure you check "Common Tools for Visual C++" in Programming language. And also be sure you have installed Windows Driver Kit (WDK)  which is a prerequisite for your guide.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are facing a [known issue For WDK](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowshardware/en-US/1fa43cc7-a82d-4dd3-8d28-f76fe2d7593e/hardware-development-kits-for-windows-10-version-1703-april-2017?forum=wdk),
You could fix it doing the following:

Known issues with the WDK
Missing files if you install both WDK 10 versions 1607 and 1703
Some WDK files are removed when installing the WDK for Windows 10, version 1703, on top of the WDK for Windows 10, version 1607.
To restore these files:
1. On the Start menu, enter "Apps & features" in the search box, and select "Apps & features" from the results. 
2. Find Windows Driver Kit - Windows 10.0.15063.0 from the list of Apps & Features and then select the program. 
3. Select Modify, select Repair, and then follow the directions on the screen. 
4. The files will be restored.

Also, see how to install WDK:
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/windows-driver-kit